# HttpRequestHeader cookie format

Tags: c#, .net, http, web

In which format does HttpRequestHeader.Cookies need to be specified? F.e, if I want to add cookie named CITY with value NY how should I do that with WebClient.Headers.Add() method?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this sample

```
  WebClient wb = new WebClient(); 

    wb.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "CITY=NY");
```

For many cookies:

```
wb.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "cookiename1=cookievalue1; cookiename2=cookievalue2");
```

Answer (score 3):

To add a cookie it's best and easiest to use `Response.Cookies.Add();`

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("lastVisit");
myCookie.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Headers.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y280s7kx.aspx):

```
 myWebHeaderCollection.Add("CITY","NY");
```

Here is how your Cookie header should look like at the end [rfc 6265](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265.txt):

```
Cookie: CITY=NY;
```