# C# WebClient Request

Tags: c#, winforms, http, httprequest

I'm using this code to make an `HTTP` Get Request:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();

client.Headers.Add("Referer", request.ReferrerUrl);
client.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", request.Headers["X-Requested-With"]);
client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", request.Headers["User-Agent"]);
client.Headers.Add("Accept", request.Headers["Accept"]);
client.Headers.Add("X-IG-App-ID", request.Headers["X-IG-App-ID"]);

client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "mid=XFAY9AAEAAFnXjST1VtFBEymLAVV");
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "mcd=3");
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "csrftoken=PcMrIsspPEi0WmxGO1DxeVCBh9pFmp8u");
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "ds_user_id=402966926");
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "sessionid=402966926%3AfVJycxzJNsp1Cm%3A14");
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "shbid=10700");
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "shbts=1558425113.7065036"); 


Stream data = client.OpenRead(urlString);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

The response from this code is not as it should be.

This is the url:

```
https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=56066f031e6239f35a904ac20c9f37d9&variables=%7B%22id%22%3A%221197166291%22%2C%22include_reel%22%3Atrue%2C%22fetch_mutual%22%3Atrue%2C%22first%22%3A24%7D
```

I checked this with `Charles Proxy` and i saw that there is a difference in the request vs. a request that i made with Chrome.

I attach the two request data:

Chrome:
[image]
C# WebClient:
[image]

There is something wrong that i do with the request? Because in chrome i get the response as i should get and i saw that there is a difference in the request form.

Comment: Your cookie is comma separated, try to set it in `"cookiename1=cookievalue1; cookiename2=cookievalue2"` format, like in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537064/httprequestheader-cookie-format) `Accept` and `User-Agent` are also different, try to set it explicitly

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski It was working with this user agent and accept too. The problem is that the request itself not looking the same in the start(the get vs. method, scheme....)